# Error con IONIC emulate android!

Tags: android, ionic

No quiere emular, arrojándome el siguiente error:

> :transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>
> Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 31.18 secs
>
> Error: /Users/Hernan/Desktop/estudiom/casaco/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   Note: /Users/Hernan/Desktop/estudiom/casaco/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/splashscreen/SplashScreen.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>       at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>       at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

  IONIC INFO:

  ```
  Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
  Gulp version:  CLI version 1.2.2
  Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
  Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.1
  Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0
  Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.0-beta.1
  ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
  ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
  OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
  Node Version: v6.5.0
  Xcode version: Xcode 8.0 Build version 8A218a
  ```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que la solución mas optima es eliminar `android-support-v4.jar` desde su proyecto ***Ionic***,

*MyProject -> Platform -> Android -> libs -> REMOVE Android-support*

Si no encuentras en esta ruta el **jar**, puedes buscarlo en plugins `cordova-android-support-v4.jar`.

Comment: No me aparece esa ruta

Comment: tampoco en Plugins -> Cordova-android-support?

Comment: no lo puedo econtrar

Comment: Voy a seguir averiguando para poder ayudarte!

Comment: siempre me ayudas sioesi, premio al  mejor de stackoverflow

Comment: @sioesi porque borrar el .jar en verdad no es necesario en Ionic?

Answer (score 0):

El problema que noto es:

> UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main :
>   Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main :
>   Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

y veo que tienes instalado Android SDK 23 y 24, por lo tanto te sugiero principalente **instalar Java 8**:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html

y configura el nuevo path, que sería algo similar a  :

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_06
```

Prueba nuevamente.

---

- Si estas definiendo como target para tu proyecto Android SDK 23 no debes tener problema, de hecho si tienes definido Android SDK 24 puedes cambiar a 23 y se solucionaria el problema.
- **Si usas Android SDK 24 como target se tiene que instalar Java 8**

Es lo que te recomiendo ya que en algún momento tenemos que realizar la actualización si deseamos continuar usando el Android SDK.